# Cordova push notifications no relying on we view

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am building an app with tabris.js and I am looking for a Cordova plugin for push notifications that does not rely on webview.
I am yet to find such thing.
Wondering if there is any plugin like it and tabris does not use webview and therefore the popular plugins I have found fail.
Regards 
PC

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin at
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin to receive push notifications.

Comment: In addition, OneSignal (http://onesignal.com) is very good. It works on almost all platform. I'm working with it now on my tabrisjs app. Bestbof all, it is free unlimitedly.